# Subclipse how to overwrite changed files

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

In subclipse (the svn plugin on Eclipse) how do I update my code to match the repository as if I had used the --force command line option? I need to overwrite everything, even the changed stuff. Team->Update adds notes about mismatches in files, breaking the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try synchronising first, and then use `override-and-update`.

`Team` -> `Synchronize with repository`, then in `Team Synchronizing` perspective choose, `Override and Update`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. That's right-click file, `Team`-> `Synchronize with repository`, in Team perspective right-click file, `Override and Update`.